# Android: Getting the View added with LayoutInflator

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, layout-inflater

Java or C# answers are fine (we use MonoDroid)

I successfully add a control to a LinearLayout with:

```
    LayoutInflater _inflatorservice = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    var viewContainer = _inflatorservice.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ReportItImageButton, myLinearLayout);
```

How do I then get a reference to the view just added? I add many of the same control this way so would need to get the nth item added to the layout.

Comment: ((View) viewContainer) ?

Comment: That gives me the linearlayout container, but not what was just added

Comment: Could you post your ReportItImageButton.xml layout? If you're getting a `LinearLayout` returned from `Inflate`, that's probably what you're inflating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, it gets the most recent item added assuming the item is of type `Button`.

```
LayoutInflater _inflatorservice = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(
    Context.LayoutInflaterService);
var layout = _inflatorservice.Inflate(
    Resource.Layout.ReportItImageButton, layoutImages) as LinearLayout;

if (layout != null)
{
    var b = layout.GetChildAt(layout.ChildCount - 1) as Button;
    if (b != null)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your XML file isn't perfect. It's better to exclude LinearLayout from it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional parameter. It **doesn't** add your inflated view to `myLinearLayout`, but still returns the `View` object of it.

```
var viewObj = _inflatorservice.Inflate(
    Resource.Layout.ReportItImageButton, myLinearLayout, false);
```

Note that, for example, if you added a `LinearLayout` then you'll get a `LinearLayout` back. This method returns the **root** view of your XML layout so it can be any type of `View`.

Answer (score 1):

```
View v = myLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.myViewId)
```

myViewId should be the same as the id specfied in your ReportItImageButton.xml file