# Get view from Resource Layout in xamarin or monodroid

Tags: android-widget, xamarin.android, xamarin

I try to get MapView from Resource Layout but it returns null:

```
 var map_view = FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.emap);
```

mylayout.xml like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/etklmap"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
android:id="@+id/zoomOutButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Zoom Out" />

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
   android:id="@+id/emap"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:apiKey="apikey" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So is there any way to get view without calling `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.mylayout);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource file is just XML - it doesn't become a collection of viewgroups and widgets until it's "inflated"

One way to inflate XML is to use SetContentView.

Another way is to use the inflaterservice - see this monodroid question (and answers) for an example: [Android: Getting the View added with LayoutInflator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985949/android-getting-the-view-added-with-layoutinflator)

---

Note that - under the covers - all setcontentview does is to inflate the XML using exactly the same inflaterservice, passing in the activity as the parent frame for the inflation.

---

The official android docs on this are http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html